# Adding GraphicCircular Apple Watch Complications to an existing Xcode Project

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I can't find any documentation online that explains how to add any of the new "graphic" complications available on the Watch Series 4.  These are my steps:

(1) added class that conforms to `CLKComplicationDataSource` (code below) 
(2) set complications configuration to point to (1) and Complications asset folder 
 [image]
(4) exported pngs from Sketch and dragged into the Complications asset folder to Modular/Utilitarian/Circular
Graphic (Corner, Bezel, and Circular) placeholders in Complications asset folder would not accept pngs (only pdfs).[image]  After all this the old Modular Utilitarian and Circular complications work fine, however the images (pdfs) for the Graphics (Corner, Bezel, and Circular) do not render on device [image]

```
import Foundation
import ClockKit

class HockeyTrackerComplication: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
    func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
        handler([])
    }

    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 5.0, *) {
            if complication.family == .circularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Circular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .utilitarianSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Utilitarian") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .modularSmall {

                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "Modular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicCircular {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicCircular") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicBezel {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicBezel") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else if complication.family == .graphicCorner {
                let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerCircularImage()
                guard let image = UIImage(named: "GraphicCorner") else { handler(nil); return}
                template.imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: image)
                let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
                handler(timelineEntry)

            } else {

                handler(nil)

            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was that I wasn't implementing `getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for:withHandler:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationdatasource/1650686-getlocalizablesampletemplate while it's listed as optional and not part of the required methods of `CLKComplicationDataSource` implementing it made my images show up in the complication.

Comment: This also helped me. Without the method call the images would not show up. I tried both with PDF and individual sizes. but this was the solution

Answer (score 4):

1. convert next:

   - UIImage name: "GraphicBezel" -> "Complication/GraphicBezel"
   - UIImage name: "GraphicCircular" -> "Complication/GraphicCircular"
   - UIImage name: "GraphicCorner" -> "Complication/GraphicCorner"
2. Image Assets, Config Image Set > Screen Width > Individual Width
   And set image to watch size area(38mm, 40mm, 42mm, 44mm).

it's work for my case.